# TeX in matplotlib on Mac OS X and TeX Live

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, tex

I have the following Hello World code to try out TeX rendering with matplotlib on my Mac.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='serif')

plt.text(2,2,r"Hello World!")
plt.show()
```

With that code, I'd get the following error:

```
sh: latex: command not found
Exception in Tkinter callback
<... a long Traceback here ...>
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX:
```

I don't see any kind of full report after the last line. Anyway, I think this is a path problem. Some pointers on how I could fix it? I have TeX Live 2010.

I tried adding `/Library/TeX/Root/bin/universal-darwin` to the Global Python Path of the Project Properties, but I still get the same errors.
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In future you might want to mention that you're running the code from NetBeans.  The Python path is not `$PATH`, instead it's `sys.path`, the path from which Python code is loaded.  You need to set `os.environ['PATH']` in your Python code; with TeX Live the preferred way to reference the current TeX installation is `/usr/texbin`.

Comment: Right about the NetBeans part. This is my 3rd question on the same topic this week. I thought I already put it in. I also couldn't add `/usr/texbin` which I got from `which latex` on the Terminal. Clicking "Add..." won't let me manually type in a path. Can you give an example of how to use `os.environ`? Its [entry](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-parameters) in the documentation doesn't have a usage example.

Comment: os.environ is just a Python dictionary. You can manipulate it like any other.

Comment: I got it now. `os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ':/usr/texbin'` Thanks!