# Python: Unable to Render Tex in Matplotlib

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, osx-snow-leopard, tex

I recently upgraded my laptop to Snow Leopard, updated TeX to Version 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2011/MacPorts 2011_5), and installed Python 2.7.3.  After all these installs, I ran macport selfupdate and macport upgrade outdated.  However, now when I try to use TeX in matplotlib, I receive the following:

```
LaTeX was not able to process the following string:'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX: 

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011/MacPorts 2011_5)
 restricted \write18 enabled.  
entering extended mode (./64a53cc27244d5ee10969789771e33fa.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, cz
ech, slovak, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, basque, french, german-x-2009-06-1
9, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, german, ngerman, swissgerman, italian, polish, portugu
ese, spanish, catalan, galician, ukenglish, loaded.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

! LaTeX Error: File `type1cm.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)


l.3 \renewcommand
             {\rmdefault}{pnc}^^M
No pages of output.
```

Similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082126/tex-in-matplotlib-on-mac-os-x-and-tex-live), I tried setting the path in my python code via:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + ':/opt/local/bin/latex'
```

since `which latex` yielded `/opt/local/bin/latex`.  However, that didn't work, with the same error message.  I also tried the path to tex, as well as the example from the previous question.  No change.

I then tried to force possibly missing packages via:

```
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{amsmath}"]
```

however, that also did not work.

The only way I can get my plots to work is to say `rc('text', usetex=False)`, which is not ideal.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: this fixed for me `sudo apt-get install dvipng`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The error message says you're missing the `type1cm` package. It seems that [MacPorts includes it as part of `texlive-latex-extra`](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages).

Comment: Still applicable on my Ubuntu 13.10 machine.  I also needed the dvipng package.

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04.1 I needed to install both `texlive-latex-extra` and `texlive-fonts-recommended`

Comment: Same on ubuntu 15.10 ... However, matplotlib continued using cached versions of plots generated **before** installing these packages. Before installing these packages, matplotlib would generate plots with no text at all. It took me a little bit to realize the cached versions were being used, but removing the dvi's and pdfs in `~/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/` did the trick.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, `texlive-latex-extra` `texlive-fonts-recommended` and `dvipng` were needed.

Comment: Any idea what to add on a windows machine? tried to add type1cm and it says package not found on miktex. thanks

Comment: The miktex.org search does find a type1cm package: http://www.miktex.org/packages/type1cm

Comment: Under Arch/Manjaro it's called `texlive-latexextra`.

Comment: ...a couple of years later macport has it in `texlive-lang-other`

Answer (score 99):

On an Ubunutu 14.04 machine the combination of answers from above worked. I `sudo apt-get install` the `dvipng`,`texlive-latex-extra`, and `texlive-fonts-recommended` packages and that did the trick:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dvipng texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Edit: As of Matplotlib 3.2.1, you now also need the package `cm-super`
(see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16911)

```
$ sudo apt-get install dvipng texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended cm-super
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu16.04 as well.

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu 16.04.1 in the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: I can generate plots, but they have serif fonts.

Comment: Update 09/2021: This works on Ubuntu 21.04 as well.

Comment: Similar issue on windows (behind a firewall). Adding cm-super solved it.

Comment: Also works for 22.04 =)

Answer (score 45):

I had to install the `cm-super` package in a ubuntu derivate ([jupyter/minimal-notebook](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-minimal-notebook) which derives from Ubuntu 18.04)
`$ sudo apt-get install cm-super`

Comment: Indeed, `cm-super` was needed on Ubuntu 18.04 along with `dvipng` `texlive-latex-extra` `texlive-fonts-recommended`.

Comment: I also needed `cm-super` on (LM) Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Also did the trick for me. I had previously sudo apt install texlive (which includes texlive-fonts-recommended). Had to install also: cm-super and texlive-latex-extra (with apt-get, for whatever reasons it didn't work with apt).

Comment: Installation of `cm-super` also did the trick for me in **Ubuntu 19.10**, but with two caveats: (i) now the plot takes way too longer to be rendered, (ii) my font styles has been affected (which I don't want it to happen)

Comment: @kmario23 I'm not sure on why it should take longer to render, but for the fonts I assume that it might make sense. Could you [check what fonts are used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27817912/find-out-which-font-matplotlib-uses) to render the plot without latex (default, or `rc('text', usetex=True)`), and what fonts are used once  you `rc('text', usetex=True)`?

Answer (score 3):

Along with `dvipng texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended`, `cm-super` was also need in `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Answer (score 0):

On Manjaro (Arch), I only needed to install `texlive-latexextra`, which contains the *type1cm.sty* file.

```
pacman -S texlive-latexextra
```

The packages `texlive-bin` and `texlive-core` were already installed on my computer and would likely also be required.