# Matplotlib failing while text.usetex==True

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, latex

I want to use Latex to create greek symbols in plot labels.  However any attempt to set e.g.

```
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

or any other version of this I could find, results in a screen full of errors even for plots in which labels aren't even used.  If I set it back to False everything is fine.  I know I should "post my attempt" but I emphasize that every example on this forum and any other webpage I can find that claims to achieve the objective fails.

The final error on the pages of errors is that type1cm.sty is not found.  Using tex Live utility I see I have it installed.

Would appreciate help for novices here as I am not exactly computer savvy.

In response to below - I am using a Mac OSX version 10.9.5.  The usual program I use for my Tex stuff is TexShop version 3.18.

Since it would appear that the iPython notebook is having problems with finding the type1cm.sty file, I would assume there is some method to tell it how to find it.

Comment: Looking at [this similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354149/python-unable-to-render-tex-in-matplotlib) it looks like telling us what your OS is might help.  Also - it's good practice to include a bit more of the error, even if you think it's not relevant. Or paste the whole lot (e.g. to http://dpaste.com/) and link to it.  You've identified that for some reason the relevant file can't be found - we probably need more information to help you with why.

Comment: By the way, on my Windows box at work I just tried this.  MikTex complained that it did not have the relevant file in the same way, but just let me install it from a repository.  So I definitely think that you need to tell us your OS and what Tex production system you're using.  That info will probably be in the error message if you're not sure.

Comment: @ J Richard Snape. Added the details requested.  Also the pointer to the other post had as an answer "The error message says you're missing the type1cm package. It seems that MacPorts includes it as part of texlive-latex-extra."  Which led me to use the Tex Live program to check what files were there and indeed the unfound file is there to be found.