# How do I get a per mille sign in my axis title using Latex in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, latex

Until now I have this:

```
plt.xlabel('$\delta^1^8$O \‰ vs VSMOW')
```

It runs fine without the promille sign, however when I add it a blank graph appears.

Then I tried TheImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer:

```
plt.xlabel(u'$\delta^{18}$O ‰ vs VSMOW')
```

But then this showed up:

"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2030' in position 264: ordinal not in range(128)"

Maybe there is something wrong with this?

```
from matplotlib import rc

rc('font', **{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
    rc('text', usetex=True)
```

**Solution** (thanks to TheImportanceOfBeingErnest)

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{wasysym}"]
```

and

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\delta^{18}$O \textperthousand vs VSMOW')
```

Comment: Whether or not you use latex (usetex), demands for completely different solutions. But I have detailed both of them in my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Using normal text

You need to

1. use a unicode string, i.e. `u"string"`
2. not escape the character, i.e. `‰` exists, but `\‰` does not.

So

```
plt.xlabel(u'$\delta^{18}$O ‰ vs VSMOW')
```

produces

[image]

#### Using latex

Latex does not have a permille sign built in. Two ways to go would be

- In text mode: use the `\usepackage{textcomp}` package and get it via `\textperthousand`,

  ```
  plt.xlabel(r'$\delta^{18}$O \textperthousand vs VSMOW')
  ```
- In math mode: use the package `\usepackage{wasysym}` and get it via `\permil`.

  ```
  plt.xlabel(r'$\delta^{18}$O $\permil$ vs VSMOW')
  ```

  Using the first package and using `\text{\textperthousand}` inside math mode should work as well.

[image]

For how to get those packages into matplotlib, read [How to write your own LaTeX preamble in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453109/how-to-write-your-own-latex-preamble-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I get now this: 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2030' in position 264: ordinal not in range(128)

Maybe there is something wrong with rc? (See question for update)

Comment: You didn't say that you were using latex in the question. I updated the answer for a way to get it in latex.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it!