# Vertical spacing in Matplotlib latex fractions

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have created fractional values for my x tick labels, but the fractions look a little cramped to me. Is there a way to increase the vertical spacing?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_xticklabels(
    ['$\\frac{{{0}}}{{{1}}}$'.format('M', x) for x in ax.get_xticks()],
    fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does the following work any better for you? plt.rc('text', usetex=True) 
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
ax.set_xticklabels(
    [r'$\frac{{{0}}}{{{1}}}$'.format('M', x) for x in ax.get_xticks()],
    fontsize=12)

Comment: @NipunBatra thank you, but that does not improve things. Also, I want my type to be san-serif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical spacing can be improved by forcing Matplotlib to use `LaTeX` rather than `mathtext`:

```
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{sansmath}', r'\sansmath']
```

The `sansmath` package retains the sans-serif type:

before: [image] after: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `\dfrac` might do the trick. However, we would need to modify the preamble.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{amsmath}')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_xticklabels(
    ['$\\dfrac{{{0}}}{{{1}}}$'.format('M', x) for x in ax.get_xticks()],
    fontsize=12)
```

[image]

Some more information here: [How to write your own LaTeX preamble in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453109/how-to-write-your-own-latex-preamble-in-matplotlib)