# Is there a way to print a matrix in the matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I know there is a way to TeX inside the legend, but it doesn't understand arguments such as a line break or the matrix environment. I haven't been able to find any other resources that address drawing out a small matrix inside the legend itself, or even overlaying the matrix onto the plot.
This is the best I can get:
[image: Plot]

with this code:

```
plt.plot(perturbation, errors,label=r'$A=[ 3  2 ][ 4  3 ]$')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'size': 12})
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/tex_demo.html — in short, `matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`

Comment: If I were to plot a fraction this would work fine, but it doesn't understand the matrix environment still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it works

```
In [7]: import numpy as np
   ...: import matplotlib
   ...: matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
   ...: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: t = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 100)
   ...: s = np.cos(4 * np.pi * t) + 2
   ...: 
   ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4), tight_layout=True)
   ...: ax.plot(t, s)
   ...: 
   ...: ax.set_xlabel(r'$\left[\matrix{ 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1 }\right]$')
Out[7]: Text(0.5, 0, '$\\left[\\matrix{ 1 & 0 \\cr 0 & 1 }\\right]$')
```

[image]

Comment: I actually got it to work this way, thanks a bunch! Maybe it's because I was using the bmatrix environment?

Comment: @liveFreeOrπHard the `\matrix` macro is defined in LaTeX (no need for additional packages) for compatibility with plain TeX, on the other hand Matplotlib has a mechanism to define a LaTeX preamble (see, e.g., this [simple and to the point example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453758/2749397)) .

Comment: @liveFreeOrπHard Note that, should you load the AMS math package, `matrix` is redefined as an environment and using `\matrix{...}` as a command raises an error, as it's detailed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468390/74057).

Answer (score 4):

Matplotlib can use a LaTex engine, but you need to have it installed on your computer and set:

```
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

See here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/usetex.html

---

#### Without installing LaTeX

The default is to use mathtext, a limited set of latex.  Mathtext has not built-in matrix commands, but you can approximate it using `\genfrac{}{}{}{}{}{}`.  You do have to handle the whitespacing yourself.  Example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.ion()

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 300)
y = np.sin(x)

label = r'$A=\genfrac{[}{]}{0}{3}{\mathtt{\,3\;2}}{\mathtt{\,4\;3}}$'

plt.plot(x, y, label=label)
plt.legend(loc='lower left', prop={'size': 16})
```

Produces this plot:
[image]

Comment: This looks awesome! When I try the same though I get the error: RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'$A=\\\\genfrac{[}{]}{0}{3}{\\\\mathtt{\\\\,3\\\\;2}}{\\\\mathtt{\\\\,4\\\\;3}}$'

Comment: Make sure you leave `plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False`; i.e., don't change it from the default.