# using mathfrak in matplotlib label returns Undefined control sequence

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

When I set `text.usetex : True` in my matplotlibrc and then try to add a text or label with `\mathfrak{}` I get an error (Undefined control sequence)

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'$\\\\mathfrak{F}$'
...
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mathfrak 
                          
l.19 {\rmfamily $\mathfrak
                          {F}$}
No pages of output.
```

Other font styles such as `\mathcal{}` work without issues.

Another thing that I tried was to set `text.usetex : False` and then specify that I want to use Computer Modern as the default font but seems like matplotlib is unable to find `serif` or `sans-serif` and falls back to DejaVu Sans:

```
findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
```

Although in this last case, I can use `\mathfrak{}` without any problems.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: From the tex perseptive: you need to load one of the packages which provide `\mathfrak`, e.g. `\usepackage{amssymb}`

Comment: maybe you can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453758/2777074

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that solved it. Many thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that your problem is solved! Would be nice if you could write up an answer so users with the same problem will be able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz gave the answer that solves this.

Adding `text.latex.preamble : \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{amsmath}` to your .matplotlibrc does the trick.