# Latex assistance in plotting: " LaTeX was not able to process the following string: b'lp' "

Tags: matplotlib, latex, python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

I have successfully done everything I need to do in order to plot a CDF (common data format, not a cumulative distribution function) file and have everything great. But I keep getting this when I type plt.show():

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    305                 pass
    306             else:
--> 307                 return printer(obj)
    308             # Finally look for special method names
    309             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    238 
    239     if 'png' in formats:
--> 240         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    241     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    242         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    122 
    123     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 124     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    125     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    126     if fmt == 'svg':

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2190                     orientation=orientation,
   2191                     dryrun=True,
-> 2192                     **kwargs)
   2193                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2194                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    543 
    544     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 545         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    546         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    547         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    462 
    463         try:
--> 464             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    465         finally:
    466             RendererAgg.lock.release()

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1141 
   1142             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1143                 renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
   1144 
   1145             renderer.close_group('figure')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2407             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2408 
-> 2409         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
   2410 
   2411         renderer.close_group('axes')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1136         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1137         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
-> 1138                                                                 renderer)
   1139 
   1140         for tick in ticks_to_draw:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1076         for tick in ticks:
   1077             if tick.label1On and tick.label1.get_visible():
-> 1078                 extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1079                 ticklabelBoxes.append(extent)
   1080             if tick.label2On and tick.label2.get_visible():

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/text.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    965             raise RuntimeError('Cannot get window extent w/o renderer')
    966 
--> 967         bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    968         x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    969         x, y = self.get_transform().transform_point((x, y))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    351         tmp, lp_h, lp_bl = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent('lp',
    352                                                          self._fontproperties,
--> 353                                                          ismath=False)
    354         offsety = (lp_h - lp_bl) * self._linespacing
    355 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    228             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
    229             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(s, fontsize,
--> 230                                                                renderer=self)
    231             return w, h, d
    232 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    674         else:
    675             # use dviread. It sometimes returns a wrong descent.
--> 676             dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
    677             dvi = dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction)
    678             try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in make_dvi(self, tex, fontsize)
    421                      'string:\n%s\nHere is the full report generated by '
    422                      'LaTeX: \n\n' % repr(tex.encode('unicode_escape')) +
--> 423                      report))
    424             else:
    425                 mpl.verbose.report(report, 'debug')

RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX:
```

I haven't an idea how to fix this nor could find a solution on the Internet, I'm thinking its something I haven't installed yet or something. Please advise, if helpful I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Respectfully,
A

Full code below:

```
import spacepy as sp
from spacepy import pycdf
from pylab import *
from spacepy.toolbox import windowMean, normalize
from spacepy.plot.utils import annotate_xaxis
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
from matplotlib.dates import DayLocator, HourLocator, MinuteLocator
from matplotlib import rc, rcParams
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
import bisect as bi
import seaborn as sea
import sys
import os
import multilabel as ml
import pandas as pd
 
sea.set_context('poster')
# sea.set_style('ticks',{'axes.facecolor':'yellow'})
sea.set_style('whitegrid')
sea.set_palette('muted',color_codes=True)
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='Mono')
rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r'/usepackage{amsmath}']
 
MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION = pycdf.CDF(r'/home/ary/Desktop/Arya/Project/Data/MMS/1/HPCA/Survey/Ion/mms1_hpca_srvy_l2_ion_20151025120000_v1.0.0.cdf')
 
EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1 = MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION['Epoch'][...]
H_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1 = MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION['mms1_hpca_hplus_flux'][...]
Ion_Energy_SURVEY_ION_1 = MMS_1_HPCA_SURVEY_ION['mms1_hpca_ion_energy'][...]
 
MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time = dt.datetime(2015, 10, 25, 12, 0, 0, 908117)
MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time = dt.datetime(2015, 10, 25, 16, 22, 24, 403623)
 
dt_MMS = dt.timedelta(seconds = 15)
 
plt.close('all')
 
fig_MMS, axs_MMS = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True)
cmap = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
cmap.set_bad('black')
 
sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION = bi.bisect_left(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1,MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time)
sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION = int(sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION-(sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION/100))
lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION = bi.bisect_left(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1, MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time)
lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION = int(lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION+((len(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1)-lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION)/100))
 
if MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time.date() == MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time.date():
    stopfmt = '%H:%M'
else:
    stopfmt = '%-m/%-d/%y %H:%M'
 
title_1 = MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M')+' -'+MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time.strftime(stopfmt)
 
if dt_MMS.seconds !=0:
    title_1 = title_1 + ' with '+str(dt_MMS.seconds)+' second time averaging'
   
for j, ax in enumerate(axs_MMS.T.flatten()):
    flix_1 = np.array(H_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION,
                                          j, :].T)
 
    if dt_MMS==dt.timedelta(0):
        fluxwin_1 = flix_1
        timewin_1 = EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION]
    else:
        fluxwin_1=[[0 for y in range(len(flix_1))] for x_1 in range(len(flix_1))]
        for i, flox in enumerate(flix_1):
            fluxwin_1[i], timewin_1 = windowMean(flox, EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION],
                                                 winsize=dt_MMS, overlap=dt.timedelta(0))
            fluxwin_1[i] = np.array(fluxwin_1[i])
            for x_1 in np.where(np.diff(EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION])
                    >dt.timedelta(hours=1))[0]+sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:
                fluxwin[i][bi.bisect_right(timewin_1, EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[x_1]):bi.bisect_right(timewin_1,
                                                                                               EPOCH_SURVEY_ION_1[x_1+1])]=0
        fluxwin_1 = np.array(fluxwin_1)
 
    fluxwin_1[np.where(fluxwin_1<=0)] = 0
   
    x_1 = mdates.date2num(timewin_1)
   
    pax_1 = ax.pcolormesh(x_1, Ion_Energy_SURVEY_ION_1, fluxwin_1, shading='turkey',cmap=cmap, vmin=1,
                          vmax=np.nanmax(H_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION,:,:]),
                          norm=LogNorm())
   
    sax_1 = ax.twinx()
    plt.setp(sax_1.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    sax_1.tick_params(axis='y', right='off')
    ax.set_xlim(MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Start_time, MMS_SURVEY_ION_1_Finish_time)
    ax.set_yscale('log')
    ax.set_yticks([10, 100, 1000,10000])
    #Allows non-log formatted values to be used for ticks
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.ScalarFormatter())
 
axs_MMS[0].set_ylabel('Energy (eV)')
axs_MMS[0].set_title(title_1)
 
cbar_ax_1 = fig_MMS.add_axes([0.93, 0.15, 0.02, 0.7])
   
cb_MMS_1 = fig_MMS.colorbar(pax_1, cax=cbar_ax_1)
cb_MMS_1.set_label(r'Counts sec$^{-1}$ ster$^{-1}$ cm$^{-2}$ keV$^{-1}$')
#Sets the colorbar value range
cb_MMS_1.set_clim(1, np.nanmax(H_Flux_SURVEY_ION_1[sidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION:lidx_MMS_1_SURVEY_ION,:,:]))
#Redraws the colorbar
cb_MMS_1.draw_all()
```

---

#### Solved

The problem was that I had not installed all packages. For all users who use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS you will need to type the following commands into your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install dvipng
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extras
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

To be sure that your specific package is in a specific subgroup of latex and you need to install please refer to this [page](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages). Furthermore **THE MOST IMPORT PART OF THE SOLUTION** was the following:

Switching this:

```
[r'/usepackage{amsmath}']
```

To this:

```
[r'\usepackage{amsmath}']
```

Let this be a lesson for everyone that syntax is important and knowing whats on your computer.

Respectfully submitted,
A

Comment: Can you post a code that reproduces the issue? Otherwise you aren't so likely to get help here.

Comment: the code is just very long and didn't want to over do the question. If it helps I will edit it to reveal full code.

Comment: Vlas Sokolov the code has been posted

Comment: Have you looked at these two SO questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214214/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354149/)? They seem to have the same errors as your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Unable to Render Tex in Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354149/python-unable-to-render-tex-in-matplotlib)

Comment: I did get somewhere new but now it's reading

`This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./32bdbffd8f6218a72d20b0ffe74c7392.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 3 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))

! LaTeX Error: File `type1cm.sty' not found.` to be continued

Comment: `Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.3 ^^M
       
No pages of output.
Transcript written on 32bdbffd8f6218a72d20b0ffe74c7392.log.`

Comment: it looks like you need to install the type1cm package, as indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11357765/4118756).

Comment: Hm...Still hasn't worked yet. I have installed the following:
`dvipng` , `texlive-latex-extra` , `texlive-fonts-extra` , and `texlive-fonts-recommended`. This problem still persist however

Comment: Sounds odd, normally missing latex modules are easy to fix. Either way, I think now your problem got reduced to a tex installation issue and shouldn't be related to `matplotlib`.