# Install latex in windows so you can use in anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, latex, environment, jupyter-lab

I am trying to use latex fonts in my figures. I am using this command:

```
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
```

I get the following error:

```
 latex was not able to process the following string:
b'lp'
```

It seems like I am lacking a latex distribution on my windows computer.

I tried to solve using the suggestions found here:

[Matplotlib Error: LaTeX was not able to process the following string: 'lp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214214/matplotlib-error-latex-was-not-able-to-process-the-following-string-lp)

However, all the solutionsonly work for Ubuntu and I was not able to make it work on WSL.

Any suggestions?