# How to include the squared symbol in a graph label

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, anaconda, spyder

I want to plot the value of R2 in my graph, but I don't know how to write the "2" as an exponent. How can I do that? Below you can find the code and the plot.

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot((y_train1),(y_train_pred),'.', color='darkviolet', alpha=1, marker='o', markersize = 2, markeredgecolor = 'black', markeredgewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot((np.array((-0.1,7))),(np.array((-0.1,7))),'-', color='magenta')
plt.xlabel('True')
plt.ylabel('Predicted')
plt.title('Train')
plt.text(5, 1, "R2 score EO: {:0.2f}".format(r2_train_EO), style='italic')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answer referencing latex would work - having to install latex for such a small change is a lot of hassle. This could be achieved by just using the unicode squared symbol in the label string:

```
plt.text(5, 1, u"R\u00b2 score EO: {:0.2f}".format(r2_train_EO), style='italic')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should configure pyplot to use Latex:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Then write R^2 in your label.

Edit: the above is recommended if you also want to control fonts. If that is not needed, just write '$R^2$' in your text - this is also Latex.

Comment: it gives me this error: RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found. How can I fix it? Maybe I have to download some library?

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: The operating system is Zorin

Comment: And, please try the second option, without loading the rc library - the problem could be missing fonts

Comment: I think  you should follow the advice in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354149/python-unable-to-render-tex-in-matplotlib

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work with the last advice that you give me.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try:

`plt.text(5, 1, f"$R^2$ score EO: {r2_train_EO:0.2f}", style='italic')`

Comment: Can you explain why and provide some docs?