# ! LaTeX Error: File `type1cm.sty' not found for Windows

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, latex

I have been trying to install TeX so that I can use it in matplotlib, but I have been unsuccessful so far. I have already downloaded `Ghostscript` and `MikTeX` via the anaconda command line (see the links [1](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/miktex) and [2](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ghostscript)). When I run a python script that uses TeX, I get the error,

! LaTeX Error: File `type1cm.sty' not found

which is pretty similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11354149/python-unable-to-render-tex-in-matplotlib), with the only difference that I am using Windows. A lot of the answers there are not helpful since the OP is using Ubuntu. Does anyone have any resolution to this issue for Windows users?

Comment: Can you go to the miktex package manager and try to install the `type1cm` package there. (check both admin and user mode, sometimes miktex need things to be done in both modes)

Comment: If you want to avoid such problems in the future, I suggest to ditch miktex and use a complete texlive installation instead, this way you would never again have to worry about missing packages

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for your answer. How exactly can I do that? I am on the link https://miktex.org/packages/type1cm/files and I do not see how I can manually download the package.

Comment: Don't manually install it. Let the miktex package manager do it. See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-miktexstar for a short guide

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to a change after Matplotlib 3.2.1 ([Details here?)](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16911)

I'm using "Tex Live Shell", updating the shell and then installing the "type1cm" and "cm-super" package fixed it for me